# Replace backslash in mixed quoted string python

Tags: python, string

I'm struggling with a very simple task. I'm composing a string like the following:

```
myvalue = '001'
s = '''-where "myfield='{}'" '''.format(myvalue)
print(s)
'''-where "myfield=\'001\'" '''
```

but what I need to have is

```
expected_string = '''-where "myfield='001'" '''
print(expected_string)
'-where "myfield='001'" '
```

the `myvalue` is a variable I'm taking from somewhere so I need to put it as a string within single quotes because it is an argument of a command line tool.

I tried with `replace` and `regex` without any success.

I'm building a string to pass as parameter to `ogr2ogr` with the [where](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-where) argument, so basically an SQL statement. The string is then passed to a wrapper that *checks* if the query is correct and with `\'` it complains.

Comment: Hello may I ask you want the output to be like this? `-where "myfield='001'" `. Cause I run your first code & it works fine.

Comment: I'm just curious cause on your first part of the code I tried & the output is this `-where "myfield='001'" ` and also on your second part of the code you mentioned that , your goal is like that sooo I think I'm confused a bit sorry.

Comment: basically I want to get rid of the backslashes at all. The final output should be `"myfield='001'" ` but **not** by printing it

Answer (score 0):

You could've used double quotes instead of an apostrophe.

```
myvalue = '001'
s = """-where "myfield='{}'" """.format(myvalue)
print(s)
[OUT]:-where "myfield='001'"
```

and to remind the f-string feature which came with python 3.7, you can eliminate the format part.

```
myvalue = '001'
s = f"""-where "myfield='{myvalue}'" """
print(s)
[OUT]:-where "myfield='001'"
```

Comment: that's actually not working. I agree that with `print` the output is correct but the variable `myvalue` is still like `'-where "myfield=\'001\'" '`

Comment: I see, you will not be printing this but if you could say that where to use, then I can help. You should be able to use. As you can see, I am able to write it in a file. https://ibb.co/nkpjVbh

Answer (score 0):

use replace() function

```
myvalue = '\ 001\ '
s = """-where "myfield='{}'" """.format(myvalue)
s = s.replace("\\","")
print(s)
-where "myfield='001'"
```